# How can I divide a value in Tedit and get the fractional part of the answer in label using freepascal

Tags: freepascal

```
var
  val1: LongInt;
  val3: LongInt;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  val1 := StrToInt(Edit1.Text);
  val3 := (val1 DIV 2);
  Label2.Caption := FloatToStr(val3);
end;
```

Comment: You can't get a fractional part using integer division. `FloatToStr` on an integer value does not magically convert it into a floating point number. If you want fractional content, use floating point values.

Comment: Please format your code so that it is legible. Please write down the mathematical formula for what you wish to achieve.

Comment: @kenWhite please put me through.

Comment: Your code won't compile. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and perhaps correct your code accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do floating-point division instead of integer division.

```pascal
var
  val1: LongInt;
  val3: Double;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  val1 := StrToInt(Edit1.Text);
  val3 := Double(val1) / 2.0;
  Label2.Caption := FloatToStr(val3);
end;
```

Or:

```pascal
var
  val1: Double;
  val3: Double;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  val1 := StrToFloat(Edit1.Text);
  val3 := val1 / 2.0;
  Label2.Caption := FloatToStr(val3);
end;
```

Answer (score -2):

The answer is: Yes, but not the way you do it.

Some suggestions for your code:

-- don't call something val3 if you don't use a val2 
     (I suppose it was there for the whole part of the division)

-- val3 must be of type "float" to hold floating point numbers

-- end the var section with a semicolon ";"

-- begin procedure on a new line, end the procedure with "end" (also on a seperate line)

-- all sections / statements (begin..end = compound statement) end with a semicolon

-- you either want to do Integer division with DIV and MOD or Floating point division with / (and TRUNC and FRAC --> look them up)

-- things between Begin and End are indented (use spaces)

-- end each assignment-statement (val1:=...) with a semicolon

Think stepwise of what it is you actually want to do.

Comment: These should be comments rather than an answer

Comment: @David. Sorry, first attempt. Noted.